# How to maintain different portlet codebases for Liferay 6.0 and 6.1

Tags: java, eclipse, liferay, backwards-compatibility

In Liferay 6.1 The class **[ServletResponseUtil](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/5.1/javadocs/util-java/com/liferay/util/servlet/ServletResponseUtil.java.html)** has been moved to a different package than in Liferay 6.0:

```
//Liferay 6.0, 
// this class lives in util-java.jar in the default tomcat web app, /webapps/ROOT/lib. 
import com.liferay.util.servlet.ServletResponseUtil;

//Liferay 6.1
// class lives in portal-service.jar in  directory tomcat-7.../lib/ext/
//import com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.ServletResponseUtil;
```

The class is used in our code like this:

```
    String result = personComponentImpl.process(request); 
    response.setContentType("text/xml");

    try {
        ServletResponseUtil.write(response, result);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        if (_log.isWarnEnabled()) {
          _log.warn(e, e);
        }
    }
```

I have to maintain and improve a portlet that was written for the Liferay 6.0 release.
 Now we are considering upgrading to 6.1, but during internal testing of the portlet I discovered that there are a few line of code where the above mentioned dependency is broken. There are ClassNotFoundExceptions on 6.1 at runtime.

My eclipse project is set up for 6.0 in mind.

**What should I do now?:**

- Maintain two different branches of the portlet code. This is doable but might be too much effort in the long run
- Maintain two different Eclipse projects with one code base, but with different build paths  (this is only a general strategy, might not really work)
- Include a clever hack in the java code,  to build easily  for 6.0, once for 6.1 (maybe a factory...this is only a vague idea)
- Include a new ant task that builds + deploys for 6.1, although Eclipse is set up to build for 6.0
- Remove the dependency on ServletResponseUtil class altogether, use another class that does the same as ServletResponseUtil.
- Do something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ServletResponseUtil is not much more than a 350 lines long, extremely verbose and even buggy implementation of `response.getOutputStream().write(data);`, I would opt for "use another class that does the same".

Perhaps you should combine that with a little "do something else" and *never* rely on the stability of the Liferay API.

Comment: I am just inspecting the source of the class here http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.0/javadocs/src-html/com/liferay/util/servlet/ServletResponseUtil.html, and will now replace the old import statement (see above) with an import of my own package which will be a customized ServletResponseUtil.